# sending self to callback function outside of the class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have class GUI and a button, the button press needs to activate a function that not belong to class GUI but needs to run some of the GUI class members function.
how to I do that?
this is my button creation:

```
tk.Button(self.top_frame, text="connect to server", var=self, command=connect_to_server)
```

and this is the function:

```
def connect_to_server(gui):
    res = False
    try:
        # Create a socket object
        # write_to_log("Socket successfully created")
        ans = s.connect((SERVER_IP, PORT))
        if ans is None:
            gui.write_to_log('connection to server establish')
            gui.connection.configure(state="disable")
            res = True
            tk.Label(gui.top_frame, text="Connected", bg="green").grid(row=0, column=1)
            gui.chk_smds_state.set(tk.TRUE)
        else:
            gui.write_to_log('connection failed')
            return res

        message = receive(s)
        # write_to_log(str(message, 'ascii'))
        gui.write_to_log(message)
        res = res
    except socket.error as err:
        message = f"socket creation failed with error %s" % err
        gui.connection.configure(bg='red')
        gui.write_to_log(message)
    return res

def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit** aaded the main function for the scop understanding

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of what you are looking for. On button press, it activates function which is defined outside the class and set the text to the label

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

def set_label_text():
    my_gui.label_to_set.config(text="New text")

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.button = Button(master, text="Click me", command=set_label_text)
        self.button.pack()

        self.label_to_set = Label(master)
        self.label_to_set.pack()

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: so my_gui is global?

Comment: You need to define it  like my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)

Comment: so that means that my_gui cant be in main

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, you need to show how is your code organized

Comment: added the main function